# Make new matrix out of value of other matrix

Tags: sas

I am new to working with SAS, and I am struggling finding a solution for the following problem: I would like to get construct a matrix out of a value from another matrix. For some reason, SAS dos not allow me to do so. Please refer to a simplified version of the problem below:

```
proc iml;
x = 0.2;
interval = {0 x};
print interval;
```

SAS does not allow this operation, generating the following error:

`ERROR: Mixing character with numeric in matrix literal.`

Could anyone tell me how to fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is this your entire code? If you add a QUIT; Statement to your code, there is nothing wrong with the syntax.

Comment: Yes, this is the whole code. Adding 'quit' to the end does not seem to solve the problem either, still getting the same error message.

Comment: You need to use INSERT() to add the row/column values. https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=imlug&docsetTarget=imlug_langref_sect205.htm&docsetVersion=15.1&locale=en

Answer (score 0):

If it is just one value you could enter it as a macro via %let statement:

```
%let x = 0.2;

proc iml;
interval = {0 &x};
print interval;
quit;
```

But @Reeza's reference would be more scalable-- not scalar-- hehe :D